# Turtle won't import on python3.5 fedora 23

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I installed the tkinter packages from the fedora repo, then I ran a simple turtle code in python... A test one form a website. (with import turtle at the top)
I then tried running the following code:

```
from turtle import *
color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()
while True:
 forward(200)
 left(170)
 if abs(pos()) < 1:
   break
end_fill()
done()
```

And it got the following error

```
[max@localhost python]$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
ImportError: No module named 'turtle'
```

And now even when I run the original program it no longer works.
It gives the exact same error as the test.py program.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a virtual environment for your project then install turtle into that.

Comment: Does `import tkinter` work?  Does <python-dir>/Lib/turtle.py exist?  If `import turtle` worked before you 'installed tkinter', then tkinter was already installed.

Comment: import tkinter doesn't work. Will try running in a virtual environment though. What sort of virtual environment should I try? A full on virtual machine?

Answer (score 2):

dnf install python3-tkinter.x86_64

Comment: The `.x86_64` isn't necessary.